# Let $(y, z) = (0, 3/4).$ Find the point $(a, b)$ with $0 < a < \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $\mathbf{f}(a, b)=(y, z)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\mathbf{f} : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by:
$$\mathbf{f}(u, v) = (u − v,\sin(u) \sin(v)).$$

Let $(y, z) = (0, 3/4).$ Find the point $(a, b)$ with $0 < a < \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $\mathbf{f}(a, b)=(y, z)$.

Then prove that the function $\mathbf{f}^{−1}$ such that $\mathbf{f}^{−1}(y, z) = (a, b)$ exists and is differentiable in some neighbourhood of $(y, z).$

Im really not sure on both questions so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just use definition of function $f$ : $a=b= \pi / 3$

Comment: Ah I get it now. Do you have a clue about part 2 of the question? @ShraddheyaShendre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to Part I**

You want $$\mathbf{f}(a, b)=(y, z)=(0, 3/4)$$

Using definition :

$$\mathbf{f}(a, b) = (a − b,\sin(a) \sin(b))=(0,3/4)$$

i.e. $a-b=0 \implies a=b$

and ,
 $$\sin a \sin b =\sin^2a=3/4 \implies \sin a =+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$   (Since $0< a< \pi/2$, $\sin a$ is positive)$ \implies a= \pi/3$

$$\text{Therefore} ~ a=b= \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Do you have any idea about the 2nd part to the question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for the second question:**

$$(a,b)=(u-v,\sin u \sin v)\\
u-v=a\to u=a+v \quad  (1)\\
\sin u \sin v=b\to \sin (a+v)\sin v=b$$

So, using sum-product relation

$$\cos(a+2v)-\cos(a)=-2\sin(a+v)\sin v$$

so,

$$\cos(a+2v)-\cos(a)=-2b\to \cos(a+2v)=\cos(a)-2b\\
v=\frac{\arccos(\cos a-2b)-a}{2}\quad (2)$$

Now check the function $$g(a,b)=\left(\frac{\arccos(\cos a-2b)+a}{2},\frac{\arccos(\cos a-2b)-a}{2}\right)$$

How is $g(a,b)$?

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I don't think im too confident in proceeding so could you give me some more help?

Comment: Check the function $$g(a,b)=\left(\frac{\arccos(\cos a-2b)+a}{2},\frac{\arccos(\cos a-2b)-a}{2}\right).$$ Who is $g(a,b)$?

Comment: @B.Smith: Is it clear?

Comment: Sorry for being a nuisance, but  I've been trying to do the rest for about an hour now with no luck. Is there any chance of more help?